# Parsing error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (line 5)

Tags: arcpy, feature-class

I want to create a number of featureclass using a template featureclass

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:\new_docs\BIO-FILES\GIS_prog\Lesson1"
arcpy.CreateFeatures_management('C:\new_docs\BIO-FILES\GIS_prog\results","Precip2009Readings.shp","POINT","Precip2008Readings.shp","Disabled","Disabled")
```

When I run the above code I get:

> Parsing error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (line 5)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What happens when you run that code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because on line 5 you have opened a single quote without closing it.

Since you have used double rather than single quotes in the remainder of your code I suggest changing that single quote to a double quote.

Also, you need to let Python know that your pathnames should be interpreted as raw strings because the backslashes in a Python need to be escaped.

Try changing:

```
env.workspace = "C:\new_docs\BIO-FILES\GIS_prog\Lesson1"
arcpy.CreateFeatures_management('C:\new_docs\BIO-FILES\GIS_prog\results","Precip2009Readings.shp","POINT","Precip2008Readings.shp","Disabled","Disabled")
```

to

```
env.workspace = r"C:\new_docs\BIO-FILES\GIS_prog\Lesson1"
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\new_docs\BIO-FILES\GIS_prog\results","Precip2009Readings.shp","POINT","Precip2008Readings.shp","Disabled","Disabled")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\buo_isa\Documents\lessons\stest.py", line 5, in <module>
    arcpy.CreateFeatures_management("C:\new_docs\BIO-FILES\GIS_prog\results","Precip2009Readings.shp","POINT","Precip2008Readings.shp","Disabled","Disabled")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateFeatures_management'

Comment: hi i just edited the script and run it and i had the message above.

Comment: It's `CreateFeatureclass_management()` you should use, `CreateFeatures_management()` doesn't exist.

Comment: @YoungEngieNewton If you get new errors from the new code snippet that you are presenting then I think that should be done as a new question.